# Boost MSM library giving errors

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-msm

The below code is an example given in boost msm documentation for functor front end.

```
  #include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// back-end
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
//front-end
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
// functors
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/common.hpp>
// for And_ operator
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/operator.hpp>
// for func_state and func_state_machine
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/state_grammar.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace msm::front;
// for And_ operator
using namespace msm::front::euml;

namespace  // Concrete FSM implementation
{
    // events
    struct play {};
    struct end_pause {};
    struct stop {};
    struct pause {};
    struct open_close {};

    // A "complicated" event type that carries some data.
enum DiskTypeEnum
{
    DISK_CD=0,
    DISK_DVD=1
};
struct cd_detected
{
    cd_detected(std::string name, DiskTypeEnum diskType)
        : name(name),
        disc_type(diskType)
    {}

    std::string name;
    DiskTypeEnum disc_type;
};

// front-end: define the FSM structure
struct player_ : public msm::front::state_machine_def<player_>
{
    // The list of FSM states
    // entry and exit functors for Empty
    struct Empty_Entry
    {
        template <class Event,class FSM,class STATE>
        void operator()(Event const&,FSM&,STATE& )
        {
            std::cout << "entering: Empty" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct Empty_Exit
    {
        template <class Event,class FSM,class STATE>
        void operator()(Event const&,FSM&,STATE& )
        {
            std::cout << "leaving: Empty" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    // definition of Empty
    struct Empty_tag {};
    typedef msm::front::euml::func_state<Empty_tag,Empty_Entry,Empty_Exit> Empty;

    struct Open_Entry
    {
        template <class Event,class FSM,class STATE>
        void operator()(Event const&,FSM&,STATE& )
        {
            std::cout << "entering: Open" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct Open_Exit
    {
        template <class Event,class FSM,class STATE>
        void operator()(Event const&,FSM&,STATE& )
        {
            std::cout << "leaving: Open" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct Open_tag {};
    typedef msm::front::euml::func_state<Open_tag,Open_Entry,Open_Exit> Open;

    // states without entry/exit actions (can be declared as functor state, just without functors ;-) )
    struct Stopped_tag {};
    typedef msm::front::euml::func_state<Stopped_tag> Stopped;

    struct Playing_tag {};
    typedef msm::front::euml::func_state<Playing_tag> Playing;

    // state not defining any entry or exit (declared as simple state. Equivalent)
    struct Paused : public msm::front::state<>
    {
    };

    // the initial state of the player SM. Must be defined
    typedef Empty initial_state;

    // transition actions
    // as the functors are generic on events, fsm and source/target state,
    // you can reuse them in another machine if you wish
    struct TestFct
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const&, FSM&,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "transition with event:" << typeid(EVT).name() << endl;
        }
    };
    struct start_playback
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::start_playback" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct open_drawer
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::open_drawer" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct close_drawer
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::close_drawer" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct store_cd_info
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const&,FSM& fsm ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::store_cd_info" << endl;
            fsm.process_event(play());
        }
    };
    struct stop_playback
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::stop_playback" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct pause_playback
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::pause_playback" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct resume_playback
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::resume_playback" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct stop_and_open
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::stop_and_open" << endl;
        }
    };
    struct stopped_again
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        void operator()(EVT const& ,FSM& ,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            cout << "player::stopped_again" << endl;
        }
    };
    // guard conditions
    struct DummyGuard
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        bool operator()(EVT const& evt,FSM& fsm,SourceState& src,TargetState& tgt)
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
    struct good_disk_format
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        bool operator()(EVT const& evt ,FSM&,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            // to test a guard condition, let's say we understand only CDs, not DVD
            if (evt.disc_type != DISK_CD)
            {
                std::cout << "wrong disk, sorry" << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    struct always_true
    {
        template <class EVT,class FSM,class SourceState,class TargetState>
        bool operator()(EVT const& evt ,FSM&,SourceState& ,TargetState& )
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // we want to define one row with the classic look.
    bool auto_start(cd_detected const& evt)
    {
        return false;
    }

    typedef player_ p; // makes transition table cleaner

    // Transition table for player
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        //    Start     Event         Next      Action                     Guard
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
        Row < Stopped , play        , Playing , ActionSequence_
                                                 <mpl::vector<
                                                 TestFct,start_playback> >
                                                                          , DummyGuard           >,
        Row < Stopped , open_close  , Open    , open_drawer               , none                 >,
        Row < Stopped , stop        , Stopped , none                      , none                 >,
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
        Row < Open    , open_close  , Empty   , close_drawer              , none                 >,
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
        Row < Empty   , open_close  , Open    , open_drawer               , none                 >,
        Row < Empty   , cd_detected , Stopped , store_cd_info             , And_<good_disk_format,
                                                                                 always_true>    >,
        // we here also mix with some "classical row"
      g_row < Empty   , cd_detected , Playing                             , &p::auto_start       >,
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
        Row < Playing , stop        , Stopped , stop_playback             , none                 >,
        Row < Playing , pause       , Paused  , pause_playback            , none                 >,
        Row < Playing , open_close  , Open    , stop_and_open             , none                 >,
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
        Row < Paused  , end_pause   , Playing , resume_playback           , none                 >,
        Row < Paused  , stop        , Stopped , stop_playback             , none                 >,
        Row < Paused  , open_close  , Open    , stop_and_open             , none                 >
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
    > {};
    // Replaces the default no-transition response.
    template <class FSM,class Event>
    void no_transition(Event const& e, FSM&,int state)
    {
        std::cout << "no transition from state " << state
            << " on event " << typeid(e).name() << std::endl;
    }
};
// Pick a back-end
typedef msm::back::state_machine<player_> player;

//
// Testing utilities.
//
static char const* const state_names[] = { "Stopped", "Open", "Empty", "Playing", "Paused" };
void pstate(player const& p)
{
    std::cout << " -> " << state_names[p.current_state()[0]] << std::endl;
}

void test()
{
    player p;
    // needed to start the highest-level SM. This will call on_entry and mark the start of the SM
    p.start();
    // go to Open, call on_exit on Empty, then action, then on_entry on Open
    p.process_event(open_close()); pstate(p);
    p.process_event(open_close()); pstate(p);
    // will be rejected, wrong disk type
    p.process_event(
        cd_detected("louie, louie",DISK_DVD)); pstate(p);
    p.process_event(
        cd_detected("louie, louie",DISK_CD)); pstate(p);
    // no need to call play() as the previous event does it in its action method
    //p.process_event(play());

    // at this point, Play is active
    p.process_event(pause()); pstate(p);
    // go back to Playing
    p.process_event(end_pause());  pstate(p);
    p.process_event(pause()); pstate(p);
    p.process_event(stop());  pstate(p);
    // event leading to the same state
    // no action method called as it is not present in the transition table
    p.process_event(stop());  pstate(p);
}
}

    int main()
    {
        test();
        return 0;
    }
```

when i am trying to build this it is giving me error not in this file but in boost library file proto.
following are the errors that i get

```
 /usr/include/boost/proto/detail/poly_function.hpp:223:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/boost/proto/detail/poly_function.hpp:263:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("

In file included from /usr/include/boost/proto/make_expr.hpp:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/proto/core.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/msm/back/fold_to_list.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:55,
                 from ../src/msmtryouts.cpp:12:
/usr/include/boost/proto/detail/poly_function.hpp:223:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/boost/proto/detail/poly_function.hpp:263:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("


/usr/include/boost/proto/detail/deduce_domain.hpp:41:20: error: redefinition of ‘struct boost::proto::detail::sized_type<N>’
/usr/include/boost/proto/proto_fwd.hpp:113:16: error: previous definition of ‘struct boost::proto::detail::sized_type<N>’
make: *** [src/msmtryouts.o] Error 1
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well found the answer my self.

1. for redefinition problem proto_fwd.hpp is included in deduce_domain.hpp and both the files have templated structure "Sized_type",so i removed it from deduce_domain.hpp
2. missing binary operator error for that a found a workaround instead of using #elif in the file poly_function use #else #if #endif problem solved